# Does c++ operator new[]/delete[] call operator new/delete?

Tags: c++

Does c++ operator new[]/delete[] **(not mine)** call operator new/delete?

After I replaced `operator new` and `operator delete` with my own implemenation, then the following code will call them:

```
int *array = new int[3];
delete[] array;
```

And When I **also** replaced `operator new[]` and `operator delete[]`, then the above code will call **only** them.

My operators implementation:

```
void *operator new(std::size_t blockSize) {
    std::cout << "allocate bytes: " << blockSize << std::endl;
    return malloc(blockSize);
}

void *operator new[](std::size_t blockSize) {
    std::cout << "[] allocate: " << blockSize << std::endl;
    return malloc(blockSize);
}

void operator delete(void *block) throw() {
    int *blockSize = static_cast<int *>(block);
    blockSize = blockSize - sizeof(int);
    std::cout << "deallocate bytes: " << *blockSize << std::endl;
    free(block);
}

void operator delete[](void *block) throw() {
    int *blockSize = static_cast<int *>(block);
    blockSize = blockSize - sizeof(int);
    std::cout << "[] deallocate bytes: " << *blockSize << std::endl;
    free(block);
}
```

I have a second question which maybe not so related, why the code prints:

```
[] allocate: 12
[] deallocate bytes: 0
```

Instead of this:

```
[] allocate: 16
[] deallocate bytes: 16
```

Comment: Yes: "Default behavior: Returns operator new(size)"

Comment: I guess, you expect `blockSize--;` will bring you to the address where the size of block is stored. Actually this decrements pointer by `sizeof (int)`. So, what if your are on a 64 bit platform? Btw. I'm not sure whether this works for all implementations of `malloc()` (though it might work for some). Heap management is "under the hood" and the heap frames may contain much more data than simply the size.

Comment: Found this link which might be of interest [Inside CRT: Debug Heap Management](https://www.codeguru.com/cpp/w-p/win32/tutorials/article.php/c9535/Inside-CRT-Debug-Heap-Management.htm). This is for MS and VC. Other compilers with other runtime libs on, may be, other platforms might do this differently.

Comment: Be very careful with using anything that might use `new` to allocate memory (such as `std::cout`) inside your implementation, as you would get into the recursion issues.

Comment: @Scheff Thanks for the note. I fixed my code and my question to do `blockSize = blockSize - sizeof(int);` instead. But the output is still the same. Any idea why?

Comment: @NemanjaBoric Thanks for the note also. I didn't think about that and will keep it in mind from now on. (I thought `std` uses their `operator new/delete` implementation).

Comment: `blockSize = blockSize - sizeof(int);` This doesn't change anything effectively. For the 64 bit compilers (at least these I know: VC, gcc) it's not unusual that `sizeof (int)` is unequal to `sizeof (size_t)`, and I would expect that block size is rather stored as `size_t`. But, again, where the block size actually is stored (relative to your block address) is implementatoin dependent (i.e. how your resp. runtime library stores heap frames).

Comment: @Scheff It doesn't explain why my `operator new[]` doesn't get more than `12`.

Comment: @StavAlfi - The compiler *might* allocate extra memory for `new[]` to store the number of destructors to call. However this is not needed for `int`, as it has no destructor.

Comment: For `new int[3]` 12 sounds reasonable to me: `3 * sizeof (int)` = 12 (assuming `sizeof (int)` = 4).  12 bytes is the actual "payload" the `new` has to allocate.

Answer (score 3):

Since the allocation operators `new` and `new[]` pretty much do the same thing<sup>(a)</sup>, it makes sense that one would be defined in terms of the other. They're both used for allocating a block of a given size, regardless of what you intend to use it for. Ditto for `delete` and `delete[]`.

In fact, this is *required* by the standard. C++11 `18.6.1.2 /4` (for example) states that the default behaviour of `operator new[]` is that it returns `operator new(size)`. There's a similar restriction in `/13` for `operator delete[]`.

So a sample default implementation would be something like:

```
void *operator new(std::size_t sz) { return malloc(sz); }
void operator delete(void *mem) throw() { free(mem); }

void *operator new[](std::size_t sz) { return operator new(sz); }
void operator delete[](void *mem) throw() { return operator delete(mem); }
```

When you replace the `new` and `delete` functions, the `new[]` and `delete[]` ones will still use them under the covers. However, replacing `new[]` and `delete[]` with your own functions that *don't* call your `new` and `delete` results in them becoming disconnected.

That's why you're seeing the behaviour described in the first part of your question.

---

As per the *second* part of your question, you're seeing what I'd expect to see. The allocation of `int[3]` is asking for three integers, each four bytes in size (in you environment). That's clearly `12` bytes.

Why it seems to be freeing zero bytes is a little more complex. You seem to think that the four bytes immediately before the address you were given are the size of the block but that's not necessarily so.

Implementations are free to store whatever control information they like in the memory arena<sup>(b)</sup> including the following possibilities (this is by no means exhaustive):

- the size of the current memory allocation;
- a link to the next (and possibly previous) control block;
- a sentinel value (such as `0xa55a` or a checksum of the control block) to catch arena corruption.

Unless you know and control how the memory allocation functions use their control blocks, you shouldn't be making assumptions. For a start, to ensure correct alignment, control blocks may be padded with otherwise useless data. If you want to save/use the requested size, you'll need to do it yourself with something like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

// Need to check this is enough to maintain alignment.

namespace { const int buffSz = 16; }

// New will allocate more than needed, store size, return adjusted address.

void *operator new(std::size_t blockSize) {
    std::cout << "Allocating size " << blockSize << '\n';
    auto mem = static_cast<std::size_t*>(std::malloc(blockSize + buffSz));
    *mem = blockSize;
    return reinterpret_cast<char*>(mem) + buffSz;
}

// Delete will unadjust address, use that stored size and free.

void operator delete(void *block) throw() {
    auto mem = reinterpret_cast<std::size_t*>(static_cast<char*>(block) - buffSz);
    std::cout << "Deallocating size " << *mem << '\n';
    std::free(mem);
}

// Leave new[] and delete[] alone, they'll use our functions above.

// Test harness.

int main() {
    int *x = new int;
    *x = 7;

    int *y = new int[3];
    y[0] = y[1] = y[2] = 42;

    std::cout << *x << ' ' << y[1] << '\n';

    delete[] y;
    delete x;
}
```

Running that code results in successful values being printed:

```
Allocating size 4
Allocating size 12
7 42
Deallocating size 12
Deallocating size 4
```

---

<sup>(a)</sup> The difference between `new MyClass` and `new MyClass[7]` comes *later* than the allocation phase, when the objects are being constructed. Basically, they both allocate the required memory *once,* then construct as many objects in that memory as necessary (once in the former, seven times in the latter).

---

<sup>(b)</sup> And an implementation is allowed to not store *any* control information inline. I remember working on embedded systems where we knew that no allocation would ever be more than 1K. So we basically created an arena that had no inline control blocks. Instead it had a bit chunk of memory, several hundred of those 1K blocks, and used a bitmap to decide which was in use and which was free.

On the off chance someone asked for *more* than 1K, the got `NULL`. Those asking for less than or equal to 1K got 1K regardless. Needless to say, it was much faster than the general purpose allocation functions provided with the implementation.